# run commands not work C#

Tags: c#

I open CMD and write this it works:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\Rar.exe" a -r -v10000k "%userprofile%\doc.rar" "D:\*.doc*`

But when I use C# and write

```
string PathWinrar ="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Winrar\\Rar.exeWinrar\\Rar.exe";
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.Arguments = (string.Format("/C \"{0}\" a -r -v10000k \"%userprofile%\\cdoc.tmp\" \"D:\\*.doc*\"", PathWinrar));
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process.Start(Info);
```

it does not work.

Comment: "not work" is not a problem statement. Be *clear* about what behavior do you observe.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to run it through cmd.exe?

Comment: @RedSerpent Does it really matter ?

Comment: And is that a typo `string PathWinrar ="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Winrar\\Rar.exeWinrar\\Rar.exe"` You seem to have an extra `Winrar\\Rar.exe` appended to the path.

Comment: My language is not English, thank you @OndrejTucny

Comment: @RoyiNamir not really, just wondering since cmd.exe seems unnecessary

Comment: Why do u think "cmd.exe" should know about `PathWinrar`? Hint: remove cmd.exe like @RedSerpent suggests/

Comment: i test he is not work @RedSerpent

Comment: @Muath did you check the path for Rar.exe, there seems to be an extra bit added there in the code u posted. Check my previous comment about it.

Comment: @RichardSchneider well he is passing the path as an argument to cmd.exe, but I don't really see why he needs to run it through cmd

Comment: the path true 100% , @RedSerpent

Comment: cmd.exe will substitute the `%userprofile%` variable. However, the OP should use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")` instead.

Comment: I tried did not work @Loathing ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what your command do. You don't have to run `cmd`, just run rar.exe directly with parameters.

```
string PathWinrar = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\Rar.exe";
string userProfile = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.Arguments = "a -r -v10000k \"" + userProfile + "\\doc.rar\" \"D:\\*.doc*\"";
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
Info.FileName = PathWinrar;
Process.Start(Info);
```